# Debugging: how to view behind the scenes calls? - Python, PyQt

Tags: python, debugging, pyqt

This seems like a somewhat simple question that I'm having a lot of trouble finding an answer for, perhaps I haven't found the words programmers use to talk about this.

I am a relatively inexperienced programmer, and have run into some difficulties with troubleshooting an application I have made. The question I have could be general, because I haven't found an answer to this for any language, but for me I'm specifically using python and PyQt4:

Is there any way to view the behind-the-scenes calls made when I execute a method/call a command? I can use debugging software (in my case winpdb) to track which lines in my code are called, but, aside from traceback info given after an error, haven't figured out how to follow the program's steps "behind the scenes". This would be helpful for cases where there hasn't been a programming error from the compiler's point of view, but the behavior is unexpected because the programmer doesn't have a complete understanding of a module's inner workings.

To put it another way: I want to know about the code that *I didn't write*. I want to know what is triggered after a line of my code is called. If I call a method like len(), python calls its own methods that will eventually return an integer to me. I'm hoping there's a way we can see what python does in between my lines of code.

If this has been asked before, please let me know, and accept my apologies for repeating the question, but I haven't been able to find an answer to that question, or at least the best way of asking it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `pdb` allows you to do more than track what lines are called, you can step through your code and inspect local variables.  If that's too clunky you can drop a `import code; code.interact(local = locals())` in wherever you want to inspect.  Leaving this as a comment because I don't know that your question is answerable as-is; I don't know what you expect when you say "behind the scenes."

Comment: Thanks roippi, I was aware of being able to inspect local variables with pdb, and it looks like your second suggestion essentially accomplishes the same task, after looking at the docs. Maybe an example will make it clearer: if I have a ListView and a Model that gives data to that view, and a user clicks on the view, there are a number of things that python does behind the scenes: it sends mouseclick events, it might send a selectionChanged signal, the view might request data from the model, etc. I would like to see the inner commands of a module. Sorry for being vague, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your requirements are, but using [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile) with [Gprof2Dot](https://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot#About) will generate a png of your code's call graphs and the amount of time spent in each function/method.

Just:

1. [grab gprof2dot.py](https://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot#Download)
2. [Use the given sample code](https://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot#python_cProfile_%28formerly_known_as_lsprof%29)

Comment: Thanks Dale, I just checked that out and it's really cool! I didn't know anything about profiling. But the idea I'm not getting across, is that I want to know about the code that _I didn't write_. I want to know what is triggered after a line of my code is called. If I call a method like len(), python calls its own methods that will eventually return an integer to me. I'm hoping there's a way we can see what python does in between my lines of code. Does that make sense? I'm going to edit my question with this and see if that helps. Thanks a lot, Dale, and sorry I can't be clearer.

Comment: cProfile will profile Python code. I don't think cProfile will profile C code or the built-in methods. [This wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) tells you how fast certain operations are for certain Python data structures. If you want to know how something works underneath the covers, look at the source.

Comment: Thanks again Dale, I suppose looking at the source is going to be the way to go. I was hoping for some type of interactive program that would help you follow that code's execution like debuggers do with our code, so maybe the answer to my question is "you can't", but you can look at the source code. If you repost your comment as an answer (keeping in mind I wasn't actually looking for profiling, very good stuff though), I'll gladly accept it. Thanks.

Comment: You can always run [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) to trace Python code via the debugger. I don't think it steps into C code or the Python built-ins though.